# Rabbitmq Confirm Listener does not work

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm trying to use the ConfirmListener but the execution never reaches its methods. I'm doing it like this:

```
    channel.addConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {

        public void handleNack(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Not ack received");
        }

        public void handleAck(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Ack received");
        }
    });

    channel.exchangeDeclare(directExchangeName, directExchangeType, DURABLE, AUTO_DELETE, arguments);

    channel.queueBind(directQueueName, directExchangeName, routingKey);

    // AUTO_ACK = false
    channel.basicConsume(directQueueName, AUTO_ACK, routingKey, directConsumer);
```

Then I publish with this:

```
        channel.basicPublish(directExchangeName, routingKey, MANDATORY, properties, message.getBytes());
```

And later I consume with this:

```
            @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {

            // Send ack
            channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
        }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call 

`channel.confimSelect();`

to enable publisher confirmations.

But I wonder if also you're hoping that the addConfirmListener will get called when the message is processed by your consumer. The ConfirmListener for publishing is triggered by the server when it accepts a message, it is not connected to the acknowledgement from your consumer.

Comment: Is there any way to listen/wait for the acks from my consumer on the publisher side?

Comment: No, you need to setup your own message passing if you want to get a reply at the publisher. Spring AMQP supports this in a decent way, though I'd recommend an asynchronous API around it.

Comment: Note to future googlers... there is a typo in this answer. It's "channel.confirmSelect()" ... missing an "r"